# How to get a strongly typed object from xml using c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I created a class model that looks like this.

```
public class SiteDefinition
    {
        [XmlAttribute ()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute()]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public List<MasterPage>? MasterPages { get; set; }
        public List<File>? Files { get; set; }
        public List<PageLayout>? PageLayouts { get; set; }
        public List<Feature>? Features { get; set; }
        public List<ContentType>? ContentTypes { get; set; }
        public List<StyleSheet>? StyleSheets { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, using a console app, I generated an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SiteDefinition xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="ContosoIntranet" Version="1.0.0.0">
  <MasterPages>
    <MasterPage Url="" Name="seattle.master" LocalFolder=".\seattle.master" ServerFolder="_catalogs/ContosoIntranet/" UIVersion="15" />
  </MasterPages>
</SiteDefinition>
```

Code I used:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var siteDefinition = new SiteDefinition();
            siteDefinition.Name = "ContosoIntranet";
            siteDefinition.Version = "1.0.0.0";
            siteDefinition.MasterPages = new List<SiteProvisioningFramework.MasterPage>()
            {
                new MasterPage(){
                    Name="seattle.master",
                    ServerFolder ="_catalogs/ContosoIntranet/",
                    UIVersion = "15",
                    Url="",
                    LocalFolder = ".MasterPages/seattle.master"
                }
            };


            Utilities.XmlHelper.ObjectToXml(siteDefinition, @".\Sample.xml");
        }
```

I just did that to know how the xml would look like, in my app, users(developers), will give the app an xml file, and then I want to convert it to a strongly typed object: `SiteDefinition`

How can I achieve this with the less effort(lines) possible?

```
private void HandleAppInstalled(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
        {
            using (ClientContext cc = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
            {
                if (cc != null)
                {
                    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                    doc.Load(@"/SiteDefinitions/SiteDefinition.xml");

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Do you already _have_ a class definition and just need to deserialize it, or are you looking to _generate_ one from the XML?

Comment: See [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx)

Comment: You're not going to get it any simpler than using the XML Serializer or the Data Contract Serializer. They best you'll be able to do is wrap the use of a serializer.

Comment: I need to convert that XML file to an strongly typed object (SiteDefinition), thats it.!

Comment: Use the [XML Serializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on following

```
    public class SiteDefinition
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public List<MasterPage> MasterPages { get; set; }
        public List<File> Files { get; set; }

        public List<PageLayout> PageLayouts { get; set; }
        public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
        public List<ContentType> ContentTypes { get; set; }
        public List<StyleSheet> StyleSheets { get; set; }
    }

    public class MasterPage
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string ServerFolder { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string UIVersion { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Url { get; set; }

        [XmlAttribute]
        public string LocalFolder { get; set; }
    }

    public class StyleSheet
    {
    }

    public class ContentType
    {
    }

    public class Feature
    {
    }

    public class PageLayout
    {
    }

    public class File
    {
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SiteDefinition));
        using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("Data.xml", FileMode.Open))
        {
            var siteDefinition = (SiteDefinition)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
```

Please note, this expression is incorrect `public List<MasterPage>? MasterPages` reference type can't be nullable. Here's more about [Nullable Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx)

And here's additional info about [XML Serialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58a18dwa.aspx)

Comment: what is that Fact attribute??

Comment: It's xUnit attribute, like `[Test]` in the NUnit or `[TestMethod]` in the MSTest